# migrating from analytics.js to gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

How would you migrate a ga create command that uses the allowLinker and siteSpeedSampleRate parameters to the gtag config command?

ga('create' 'UA-1234567-25', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true,'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100
});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"linker" will allow you to accept incoming cross domain.
"site_speed_sample_rate" will allow you to adjust the site speed sampling rate.

```
  gtag('config', 'UA-1234567-25', 
    {
      'linker': {'accept_incoming': true},
      'site_speed_sample_rate': 100
    });
```

Comment: Is "site_speed_sample_rate" officially documented anywhere?  Thanks